# Does removing an element also remove its event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html

An event associated with an item is removed if you also remove the element with `removeChild()`? Even if the item is removed with a simple `this.innerHTML =''`? The same applies to an event associated to an inline element like this `<div onclick="/*this event*/"> </div>`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to know if they remain the same in memory...

Comment: I think it depends from browser and its garbage collector.... but i'm not sure

Comment: `removeChild()` - it removes all the info inside element and of course it removes it's `onclick` etc

Comment: @EL [Are you sure](http://jsfiddle.net/Hm8GE/2/)?

Comment: So in short what are the 3 answers to my 3 questions?

Comment: why not just remove the listeners like you're supposed to ?

Comment: @Teemu I think so. If anyone explain me how to invoke `onclick()` of some element when that element is deleted, I'd take back my words =)

Comment: @EL Well, you can't click on a deleted element, but as you can see in my fiddle, a removed element can be returned. An event handler still consumes memory, if there's a reference to the removed element. How much, is a different thing. If there's a named function to handle an event, it'll be there after deleting the element too. Keeping just a reference to a handler function consumes only few bytes... My comment to you (and the fiddle) was posted just to show, that `removeChild()` doesn't necessarily remove the element in its argument from the memory.

Comment: @Teemu Sincerelly, I was surprized that `removeChild()` doesnt removes, so I'll delete my previuos statements, but I'm sure when it's cleared via `innerHTML=''` that it's really cleared. Or? .....oops, can't delete it.

Comment: @EL Not even with removing `innerHTML` of the parent element. Please check the linked fiddle in my comment to Krasimir's answer. Only if there's no reference to the element, it's really removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made the following test:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
        var link = document.querySelector("a");
        link.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log("click");
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            wrapper.innerHTML = "";
        }, 4000)
    }
</script>
```

and monitor the results in the dev tools. After the loading of the page the events attached become from 5 to 6. The link is removed from the DOM and the events listeners become 5 again.

[image]

Comment: So inline events are also removed with innerHTML right?

Comment: @user2809046 [Nothing is really removed](http://jsfiddle.net/Hm8GE/3/), if you still have a reference to the element, as said in Tibos' answer. In case there's no reference, the element and its members are removed ofcourse.

Comment: So you advise me to remove the events manually? And how do to events inline?

Comment: @user2809046 Inliners are gone with the element too. Just take care, there's not a reference to the element (like global `but` in my fiddle), and you can safely remove the element only. If there is a reference, you can remove the eventlisteners manually, but the element itself remains in the memory, no matter what you'll do..., except when removing the reference too.

Comment: I just run the same test but with inline click handler. The handler wasn't even counted by the Chrome's timeline, which is kinda interesting.

Comment: @Krasimir I guess that's because an inline event handler is just a value of an attribute.

Comment: In practice, I should leave everything as it is, right?

Comment: @user2809046 I'd test the code in the same way as Krasimir has done. Then you can be sure. Like said many times here, removing depends on the existing references to the element...

Answer (score 9):

The answer is that it depends whether you have references to it or not.

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
otherElement.appendChild(d);
otherElement.removeChild(d);
// still have reference to d, it will exist, event listener remains even if it won't be fired.
```

If you no longer have a way to access it, the element will be garbage collected along with the  listeners (for all browsers > IE6).

Comment: Also in IE<7, if there's not an existing reference to the element in the event handler itself. I.e. there's not a variable declared like `var elem = event.srcElement;` In IE<7 `elem` causes a memory leak, when removing the element having this handler.